# need workflow formula if age is between 18 and 20 i should get confirmation email

Tags: workflow

need workflow formula if age is between 18 and 20 I should get confirmation email

```
IF ((TODAY() –  Birthday__c) / 365 < 30, “20-29”,
```

Comment: so what is a question? is something not working?

Comment: yes i have mentioned my formula that is not working. IF ((TODAY() –  Birthday__c) / 365 < 30, “20-29”,

Comment: It's a good idea to provide as many details as possible so that people don't need to guess at what "not working" means. The less people need to guess, the higher your chance of receiving high-quality (and accurate) answers. Some information that would be good to share includes: - the full text of any error messages - a description of what you expect your code/formula/workflow to do - a description of what your code/formula/workflow _is currently doing_. You can include this information by making an [edit] to your question.

Answer (score 2):

you can use formula to calculate Age from [How to calculate the age for a Contact?](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=How-to-calculate-the-age-for-a-Contact&language=en_US&type=1) article.

Create new formula field:

```
IF( NOT( ISBLANK( Birthdate ) ) ,
  IF( DATE( 2000 , MONTH( Birthdate ) , DAY( Birthdate ) ) <= DATE( 2000 , MONTH( TODAY() ) , DAY( TODAY() ) ),
     YEAR (Today()) - YEAR ( Birthdate ),
     YEAR (Today()) - YEAR ( Birthdate ) -1 ),
  null)
```

Add workflow criteria based on your requirements